# How to initialize circular animated timer at specific position in android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-timer, android-paint

The timer always starts from the top, and I want it to start from some initialized position with some part already drawn. I took reference from [this tutorial](https://blog.maxwellforest.com/drawing-an-animated-timer-in-android/).

**This is my MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int TIMER_LENGTH1= 3600*24;
    private static final int TIMER_LENGTH2= 3600;
    private static final int TIMER_LENGTH3= 60;
    private static int i=0;
    private TextView tvDay, tvHour, tvMinute, tvSecond, tvEvent;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout1, linearLayout2;
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;
    private TimerView mTimerView1,mTimerView2,mTimerView3;
    private static long h=0,m=0,s=0,d=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
        initUI();
        countDownStart();
        mTimerView1 = (TimerView) findViewById(R.id.timer2);
        mTimerView2 = (TimerView) findViewById(R.id.timer3);
        mTimerView3 = (TimerView) findViewById(R.id.timer4);

    }


    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private void initUI() {
        //linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll1);
        linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll2);
        tvDay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTimerDay);
        tvHour = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTimerHour);
        tvMinute = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTimerMinute);
        tvSecond = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTimerSecond);
        //tvEvent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvevent);
    }

    // //////////////COUNT DOWN START/////////////////////////
    public void countDownStart() {
        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                    try {
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "yyyy-MM-dd");
                    // Here Set your Event Date
                    Date eventDate = dateFormat.parse("2016-12-29");
                    Date currentDate = new Date();
                    if (!currentDate.after(eventDate)) {
                        long diff = eventDate.getTime()
                                - currentDate.getTime();
                        long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                        diff -= days * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                        long hours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
                        diff -= hours * (60 * 60 * 1000);
                        long minutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
                        diff -= minutes * (60 * 1000);
                        long seconds = diff / 1000;
                        if(i==0)
                        {
                            mTimerView1.start(TIMER_LENGTH1);
                            mTimerView2.start(TIMER_LENGTH2);
                            mTimerView3.start(TIMER_LENGTH3);
                            i++;
                            d=days;
                            h=hours;
                            m=minutes;
                            s=seconds;
                        }
                        if(minutes!=m)
                        {
                            mTimerView3.start(TIMER_LENGTH3);
                            m=minutes;
                        }
                        if(hours!=h)
                        {
                            mTimerView2.start(TIMER_LENGTH2);
                            h=hours;
                        }
                        if(days!=d)
                        {
                            mTimerView1.start(TIMER_LENGTH1);
                            d=days;
                        }
                        tvDay.setText("" + String.format("%02d", days));
                        tvHour.setText("" + String.format("%02d", hours));
                        tvMinute.setText("" + String.format("%02d", minutes));
                        tvSecond.setText("" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
                    } else {
                        //linearLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        linearLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        tvEvent.setText("CULFEST IS ON");
                        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                        // handler.removeMessages(0);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mTimerView1.stop();
        mTimerView2.stop();
        mTimerView3.stop();

        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

**This is my TimerView:**

```
public class TimerView extends View {

    private static final int ARC_START_ANGLE = 270; // 12 o'clock

    private static final float THICKNESS_SCALE = 0.03f;

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;

    private RectF mCircleOuterBounds;
    private RectF mCircleInnerBounds;

    private Paint mCirclePaint;
    private Paint mEraserPaint;

    private float mCircleSweepAngle;

    private ValueAnimator mTimerAnimator;

    public TimerView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public TimerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public TimerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        int circleColor = Color.RED;

        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TimerView);
            if (ta != null) {
                circleColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.TimerView_circleColor, circleColor);
                ta.recycle();
            }
        }

        mCirclePaint = new Paint();
        mCirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mCirclePaint.setColor(circleColor);

        mEraserPaint = new Paint();
        mEraserPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mEraserPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mEraserPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("SuspiciousNameCombination")
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec); // Trick to make the view square
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        if (w != oldw || h != oldh) {
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        }

        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        updateBounds();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

        if (mCircleSweepAngle > 0f) {
            mCanvas.drawArc(mCircleOuterBounds, ARC_START_ANGLE, mCircleSweepAngle, true, mCirclePaint);
            mCanvas.drawOval(mCircleInnerBounds, mEraserPaint);
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public void start(int secs) {
        stop();

        mTimerAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
        mTimerAnimator.setDuration(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(secs));
        mTimerAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        mTimerAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                drawProgress((float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });
        mTimerAnimator.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (mTimerAnimator != null && mTimerAnimator.isRunning()) {
            mTimerAnimator.cancel();
            mTimerAnimator = null;
            drawProgress(0f);
        }
    }

    private void drawProgress(float progress) {
        mCircleSweepAngle = 360 * progress;
        invalidate();
    }

    private void updateBounds() {
        final float thickness = getWidth() * THICKNESS_SCALE;

        mCircleOuterBounds = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        mCircleInnerBounds = new RectF(
                mCircleOuterBounds.left + thickness,
                mCircleOuterBounds.top + thickness,
                mCircleOuterBounds.right - thickness,
                mCircleOuterBounds.bottom - thickness);

        invalidate();
    }
}
```

The Timer looks like this:

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From glancing over the source code, it looks as though you should be able to set an initial start value in the following way:

1) Create an instance variable to store the initial value with a setter:

```
//Value between 0f and 360f
private float mStartValue = 0f;
//...
public void setStartValue(float startValueInDegrees) {
     mStartValue = startValueInDegrees;
}
```

2) Update the `drawProgress()` method to account for this new start value:

```
private void drawProgress(float progress) {
    mCircleSweepAngle = ((360 - mStartValue) * progress) + mStartValue;
    invalidate();
}
```